# Saving uploaded media content

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm making my own website using html and php, and a database using mysql on localhost on a easyPHP server. Users can make an account and upload videos on the site.

I'm wondering if it would be possible when they upload the file, it would upload the file to youtube and I can just save that link in my database. Then on the content page I could just use that link to show the video in an embedded player.

If that's not possible, what would be the best way to save the content in a folder on my PC?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Youtube allows uploading video files directly to Youtube's servers, bypassing your server.

This page documents it pretty well: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_browser_based_uploading